# How to write the test class for Pagination?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Can anyone tell me how to write the test class for pagination?
Below is my test class which covers 85%, but it doesn't cover the `hasNext`, `hasPrevious` and `pageNumber` methods.

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)  
public class PaginationControllerTest {  

        public static testMethod void testSearchAccount() {  
        PageReference pageRef = Page.TestPagination;  
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page

        PaginationController  p=new PaginationController ();

        p.getAccountList();
        p.Next();
        p.First();
        p.Last();
        p.Previous();
        p.Cancel();
        p.con.getHasPrevious();
        p.con.getHasNext();
        p.con.getPageNumber();


     }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class PaginationController {    
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {   
        get {    
                if(con == null) {    
                    con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id, Name,Type FROM Account]));     
                    con.setPageSize(5);                         
                }   
                return con;   
        }   
        set;   
    }  

    public List<Account> getAccountList(){   
        return (List<Account>)con.getRecords();   
    }   

    public Boolean hasNext {    
        get {
                return con.getHasNext();   
            }
        set;
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;   
    }

    public Integer pageNumber {   
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();   
        }
        set;
    }

    public void first() {
        con.first();
    }

    public void last() {
        con.last();
    }

    public void previous() {
        con.previous();
    }

    public void next() {
        con.next();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        con.cancel();
    }        

}
```

Comment: Try creating more than 5 Account records in your test class.

Comment: @Girbot It will give same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a example I have handy:

```
//Instantiate the StandardSetController  
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con{get; set;}


//Boolean to check if there are more records after the present displaying records  
    public Boolean hasNext  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return con.getHasNext();
        }  
        set;  
    }  

//Boolean to check if there are more records before the present displaying records  
    public Boolean hasPrevious  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }  
        set;  
    }  

//Page number of the current displaying records  
    public Integer pageNumber  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return con.getPageNumber();  
        }  
        set;  
    }
```

These lines can all be covered by simply calling them directly in your test method:

```
boolean test1 = controller.hasNext;
boolean test2 = controller.hasPrevious;
integer test3 = controller.pageNumber;
```

To clarify my create more than 5 Accounts comment - this is how I would actually test it. The above is purely for line coverage. So for example create 10 Accounts in your test method, instantiate the page/controller than assert the value of `controller.hasNext` is True